# Automatically Populate a result from each cell in Column "B" using vlookup formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am new in VBA, please help me to create a code based on the lookup value in column "B" and it will generate automatically a result in Column C, and Column H (Please see screenshot below).

[image]

[image]

[image]

Please help me correct my code (below):

```
    Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
       If Sheet1.Range("B13") = "" Is Nothing Then Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Sheet1.Range("B13"),Sheet4.Range("''''A4:D120000"),3,0)
     End If
     End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't decided what to do with the result i.e. which cell to write it to? Please do clarify.

Comment: It might be more beneficial to take a general VBA tutorial, to be honest.

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of `Sheet4(Sheet1)`?

Comment: the last screenshot is the Sheet4(Sheet1)

Comment: the result will be written in Sheet1 Column C but if the lookup value "" then do nothing or leave it blank only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the formula to the cell rather than the value.

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
   
    Const COL_DESCR = 3 ' lookup
    Const COL_PRICE = 4
    Dim descr As String, price As String, tbl As String, i As Long
    tbl = "'" & Sheet4.Name & "'!R1C1:R120000C4"
    
    descr = "=IF(RC[-1]="""","""",VLOOKUP(RC[-1]," & tbl & "," & COL_DESCR & ", 0))"
    price = "=IF(RC[-6]="""","""",VLOOKUP(RC[-6]," & tbl & "," & COL_PRICE & ", 0))"
    
    i = 13
    With Sheet1
        .Range("C" & i).FormulaR1C1 = descr
        .Range("H" & i).FormulaR1C1 = price
    End With
    
End Sub
```

or the values using `Application.Match`

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()
   
    Dim r, i As Long, rngLU As Range
    Dim price, descr As String
    i = 13
    
    Set rngLU = Sheet4.Range("A4:A120000")
    With Sheet1
    
        If .Range("B" & i).Value2 <> "" Then
            r = Application.Match(.Range("B" & i).Value2, rngLU, 0)
            If IsError(r) Then
                descr = "#N/A"
                price = "#N/A"
            Else
                descr = rngLU.Cells(r, 3) ' col C
                price = rngLU.Cells(r, 4) ' col D
            End If
        End If
        
        .Cells(i, "C") = descr
        .Cells(i, "H") = price
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way to write only the value instead of formula?

Comment: @mijnivek ok see update

Comment: SOLVED! Thank you so much!!!